# Can I put my string into Couchbase view query?

Tags: node.js, couchbase

Assume I have a view:

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if (doc.owner == "patrick_bateman") {
    emit(doc.title, doc.date);
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can put my own variable from the webapp instead of "patrick_bateman"? I need to dynamically check if the entry is owned by a specific user. If it's not possible, how do I check things like ownership of entries in Couchbase?

Comment: No, Views can't take parameters. You could construct a view though that emitted owner as a Key for example `emit(doc.owner, { title: doc.title, date: doc.date })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in your second question you can use "compound keys" for this. Here is short example of map function:

```
map: function(doc,meta) {
  if (meta.type === "json"){
    emit([doc.owner, doc.date], null);
  }
}
```

View with this map function can accept "from web app" variable "patrick_bateman" and results will be sorted by date. Also you can specify date range if you want. So query variables for that view (i.e. if you want all records owned by patrick_bateman that were created from time `0` to time `100`): `startKey=["patrick_bateman", 0]` `endKey=["patrick_bateman", 100]`. Or if you want records from time 100 till now you can use `startKey=["patrick_bateman", 100]` `endKey=["patrick_bateman", {}]`.